# Checking laptop's battery state in a terminal

Tags: command-line, power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check battery status using terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal)

I want to find out whether my laptop is plugged in to AC power or not using the command line. How can I do this?