# How can I get the percentage of my battery life from the command line?

Tags: command-line, power-management

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35920/checking-laptops-battery-state-in-a-terminal) tells me how I can find the state of my battery from the command line.

While this is useful information sometimes I need something quicker, basically like the percentage or enough for me to determine if I need to charge right away or if I can keep going for a bit longer without me having to care about milliwatts from catting my battery stats.